# java array manipulation

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java. I want the logic of the small program.

I have two arrays

```
array = {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,,,,,,,,,an}
```

and

```
array2 = {b1,b2,b3,b4,,,,,,,,,,,bn}
```

I want string as a1b1,a2a3b2b3,a4a5a6b4b5b6,.... so on up to n

Please tell me what will be the logic.

Comment: Please try to clarify your question and be more specific.

Comment: How would you do that in pencil and paper? What's the algorithm you have?  Do you want us to do the program for you or are you having an specific Java syntax problem here?

Comment: He said he is a Java beginner (more like a beginner programmer), still, most of you guys introduced StringBuilder / Buffer to him :). I think the author of the question must a bit confused now.

Comment: @Andrei: I tried to address that part in my answer. I'll happily take any other suggestions you may have.

Comment: Why don't you accept the answer given by fastcodejava?

Answer (score 3):

You need a nested for-loop. You append `span`-elements from `arr1` and `arr2` at a time, with `span` increasing from 1. This code only works if `N` is a [triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number); otherwise the last element will be "incomplete" and as of now this code doesn't handle it (and would throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`).

```
String[] arr1 = { "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6" };
String[] arr2 = { "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6" };
int N = arr1.length;
// here we assume that N == arr2.length, and N is triangular

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int start = 0, span = 1; ; span++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < span; i++) {
        sb.append(arr1[start + i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < span; i++) {
        sb.append(arr2[start + i]);
    }
    start += span;
    if (start == N) break;
    sb.append(",");
}
System.out.println(sb);
// prints "a1b1,a2a3b2b3,a4a5a6b4b5b6"
```

---

#### The logic

To understand just the underlying logic, perhaps we can start with something simpler:

```
int start = 0;
int N = 8;
int span = 1;
while (start < N) {
   System.out.println("span = " + span);
   for (int i = 0; i < span; i++) {
      System.out.println(start + i);
   }
   start += span;
   span++;
}
```

This prints:

```
span = 1
0
span = 2
1
2
span = 3
3
4
5
span = 4
6
7
8
9
```

You should understand how the nested loop structure works. Again, note that even though `N = 8` (which is not a triangular number), the loop actually prints 10 numbers (which is a triangular number). You can work on this snippet first, try to modify it so that it will *only* print `N` numbers regardless of whether or not it's a triangular number, and then adapt the same technique to the original problem.

You can also work on this snippet to print, say, `"next!"` before each `span` line, except the first. That would be the same logic to include the comma in the original problem.

Good luck!

Comment: @M. Joanis: yeah, just noticed that; fixed now.

Comment: Using a method will simplify the answer : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703259/java-array-manipulation/2703281#2703281

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
int length = 1;
for (int start = 0; start < n; start += length, length++;) {
   build(builder, a1, start, length);
   build(builder, a2, start, length);
   if (start + length < n) {
       builder.append(",");
   }
}
```

The method `build(StringBuilder builder, int[] a, int start, int end)` should be easy to 
write. This method will append `a[start]` to `a[end]` checking `end < a.length`. At the end remove the last comma.

**EDIT** : As per request from polygenelubricants providing complete answer. Above loop was changed a little as well.

```
private void build(StringBuilder sb, int[] a, int start, int length) {
    for (int i = start; i < length && i < a.length - start; i++;) {
        sb.append(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rename `end` to `length`, and you should just provide `build` at this point.

Comment: @polygenelubricants : good suggestion, fixed. Method `build` should be  easy to write.

Comment: if it's easy then _just do it_, including the last comma removal part. This is a good answer and I'd upvote once it's complete.

Comment: There's no need for `""+` as StringBuilder has append methods for any primitive, so `sb.append(a[i])` works and is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop and a [StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instance.

```
String getHomework(int[] array, int[] array2){
    final int n = array.length; //assumes len array 1== len array2
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
       builder.append(array[i]);
       builder.append(array2[i]);
       builder.append(",");
    }

    builder.append(array[n-1]);
    builder.append(array2[n-1]);

    return builder.toString();
```

}

Comment: @saching: but do you really want string as a1b1,a2a3b2b3,a4a5a6b4b5b6,.... so on up to n?  ; )

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work... haven't tested though!

```
arr1 = {a11, a12, ..., a1n};
arr2 = {a21, a22, ..., a2n};

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

int index = 0;
for (int i = 1; true; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        builder.append("" + arr1[index + j]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        builder.append("" + arr2[index++]);
    }
    if (index < n - 1) {
        builder.append(",");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where i is the number of elements to print on the iteration for each array. index is the actual index of the element to print in the array. j are just there to loop i times.